# RedirectToAction return type error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application in MVC4. 
I need to have a custom error page.
I want to redirect to the error page from the try-catch blocks of many functions.

I want to use "RedirectToAction" to do this.

The problem is in the return type. My functions use different return types. 
An example

```
private UserDetails getUserInfo(string userId)  
{
    UserDetails _userDetails = new UserDetails();
    try
    {            
        //Do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        return RedirectToAction("customErrorPage", "CreateKit", errorObj); 
    }
    return _userDetails;
}
```

The above function should return an object of UserDetails. Hence it shows error in the RedirectToAction line. 
Using Object type is not a good practice I believe.

How can solve this?

Is there any other option other than RedirectToAction?

Note:- The parameter of RedirectToAction "errorObj" is NOT same for all the functions. So if I am handling RedirectToAction outside the function, then I need to get the errorObj value also. 
I know I can pass it as an out parameter. But in my case, I have to pass it in 3-4 levels. Lot of ugly code.

Comment: you can add a property in the class as flag and set it in catch and return it,

Comment: and is this your action??

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the *try* naming convention for methods like this:

```
private bool TryGetUserInfo(string userId, out userDetails)  
{
    bool result = false;
    UserDetails _userDetails = new UserDetails();
    try
    {            
        //Do something

        userDetails = _userDetails.GetDetails();
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {              
      Logger.LogError(ex);  
    }

    return result;
}


public ActionResult SomeMethod()
{
  UserDetails userDetails;

  if (TryGetUserInfo("asdf", out userDetails))
  {
    return View(userDetails);
  }
  else
  {
    return GetErrorResult();
  }
}

public ActionResult SomeOtherMethod()
{
  if (TryGetSomethingElse())
  {
    return View();
  }
  else
  {
    return GetErrorResult();
  }
}

// reusable error message for this controller
// could derive of all controllers and change it depending
// on the controller
private ActionResult GetErrorResult()
{
  return RedirectToAction("customErrorPage", "CreateKit", errorObj); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erik for the comment. But in my case, value of "errorObj" is unique for all the functions. Please check the comment I have added with the question.

Comment: Is it really that hard to modify my `GetErrorresult()` to pass in `errorObj`?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use custom exception.

1. Create an exception class for errorObj
2. Update and throw it from the catch block
3. Catch it in the parent class
4. Redirect to the custom error page with the errorObj.

Not sure this is a good practice, but it works.

Thanks everyone for the support and effort.